# Is there a way to terminate user status in flutter when going to background

Tags: flutter

I am developing an app and one of the requests is, when the user goes from the app to the background, to another app or something like this, when they reopen it the app has to go to splash screen again so they do the pincode again.

I cant find an answer on how to do it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

use **WidgetsBindingObserver** it help to listen for app life cycle,

```
    class FooClass extends State<FooClass> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
        // ... some code
    }
```

on initState listen for app state change

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
```

override **didChangeAppLifecycleState** when app lifecycle changes this method will called with current lifecycle state

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        
    }
  }
```

and finally in dispose if you wan to remove listener

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
```

for more details
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html